# WPF application issues on windows server 2003/2008

Tags: wpf, windows-server-2008

I deployed my WPF application on windows server 2008 and its working fine when i started using of it. But after some time i'm facing so many problems with my app like its freezing some windows/controls and some windows only minimize, maximize and close buttons are working and in some windows some controls only working, any one help me please to get out of this.

Thanks,
@nagaraju.

Answer (score -1):

In a server environment, you should deactivate Hardware rendering, as most servers have only very limited GPU performance. See [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/06/22/software-rendering-usage-in-wpf.aspx), item 6, on how to set this. Please report after ensuring software rendering is enabled.

Comment: Not getting exactly, could you please tell me what need to do.

Comment: To force software rendering, set `RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly`. You can do this, for example, in your App.xaml.cs (override the OnStartup handler)

Comment: link is dead 9 years later