# Why WPF app is having issue running on Windows server?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, visual-studio

I build a WPF application in Visual Studio 2015. It's working fine on Windows 10 PCs, but when I tried to run it on Windows Server 2012 everything is messed up. Resource images were not loaded, some of the functionality stopped working.

My WPF app requires .NET 4.5 and the server has .NET 4.7 installed.

So why are things like this happening and is there any solution for it?

Comment: Not sure is it same - but check [https://stackoverflow.com/a/10698880/1565525](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10698880/1565525)

Comment: Please add more informations to your question. As it is, it can not be answered in any meaningful way. How are images embedded in your application? What functionality isn't working anymore/how is that functionality not working? Are any exceptions being generated?